# Finding the implementation of Tensorflow's softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm using Tensorflow's `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` in a neural net I'm building, and am looking for the function's source.  It doesn't seem to be defined in the GitHub repo (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow), only imported & used from a separate module.  What's the easiest way to examine the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python wrapper is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L448). The C++ implementation for the operation can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/xent_op.cc#L33).

Comment: Never link to a line without specifying what commit. Both of these are now outdated.